# Asking for the value returned by Solve

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Assume that I am in Mathematica trying to use the Function Solve and the output is $\{r \rightarrow 2, r\rightarrow 3 , r\rightarrow 4\}$, and from this I want to pick the solution $r=4$ So I have tried using the command $[[3]]$ but what I get is $r\rightarrow 4$. Is there anyway I can something else to only get $4$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999. Also `Values[rules]` gives a list of the right-hand sides of the `->`.

Comment: Say your output is `sol`. Then `r  /. sol[[3]]`. But you should read the link provided in the previous comment.

Comment: You might consider that if you're using `r` as a variable, `r=4` is not so nice, as it defines a `value` that automatically replaces `r` with `4` whenever it appears. But having a `Rule` like `r->4` is more useful, because now you have control over your replacement. Thus, an expression like `2r/.r->4` yields `8` without getting in the way of continuing to use `r` as a variable.

Comment: `List@@@{r->1, r->3,r->4}[[3,2]]`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The command Solve gives a list of Rule objects. Rule Objects have the property of replace a symbol by a value. For example,

```
Solve[(r-2)(r-4)(r-3)==0,r]
```

gives the output

```
{{r -> 2}, {r -> 3}, {r -> 4}}
```

Each sublist in the list contains a Rule object. To Make the the replacement you have to use the ReplaceAll buit-in function :

```
ReplaceAll[r, Solve[(r - 2)(r - 3)(r - 4)==0,r]]
{2,3,4}
```

or its shorthand form

```
r/.Solve[(r - 2)(r -3)(r - 4)==0, r]
{2,3,4}
```

And so you can extract the desired solution.